# How to prevent elements from overlapping in html

Tags: html, css

I have a table followed by a form with textbox. The table will be dynamically updated when user submits data. The issue here is that my table overlaps or reposition the other elements with the increase in rows. How to prevent this ?

My table and form are in same div .

CSS for the div :

```
.tabset_content {
    border: 2px solid #5ba63c;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    display: none;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi if the markup is defined say as

```
<form class="group">
 ...
</form>

 <table class="group">
 </table>

 <div id="aftertable" class="group">
 </div>
```

You can try adding a group class to each of them and CSS rules will go like

```
.group:after{
 content: '';
 clear:both;
 display:table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try `clear:both;` after each appended element.

Let say when user added comment is appened as `div` within parent `div` you may write something like

```
<div style="clear:both;">User Comment</div> // YOUR APPENDED DIV
```